# JS - Change the text depending on the user's input

Tags: javascript, jquery

First of all, sorry if the question seems really dumb, I'm not really used to Javascript.

I'm looking for a script changing some text depending on what the user wrote. Here's what I'm looking for :

- There is 3 inputs (A, B and C) for 1 Text.
- The "Text" will show the addition of A, B and C.
- Example : Input A is 3, B is 5, C is 10. Text = 18.

I got some script ready, but it's only the "bones" of the script..

```js
function ShowPointsNeeded(text){
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =text; }
```

```css
#result {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid #999; 
  font-size:25px; 
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
<input id="slide" type="text" value=""
onchange="ShowPointsNeeded(this.value);" />
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

-> It's just a basic script, showing the content of the input in a little box. Now, what I would like to have is 3 inputs and the little box to show the addition of them.

Thanks !

Comment: can you post the full html ?

Answer (score 1):

you will need to sum all input values every time `ShowPointsNeeded()` is called. you can use reduce() for this.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function ShowPointsNeeded(){
   document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = $('input').toArray().reduce((acc,cur) => acc + Number(cur.value), 0);
}
</script>  

   <div id="text">
<input id="slide1" type="text" value=""
onchange="ShowPointsNeeded();" />
<input id="slide2" type="text" value=""
onchange="ShowPointsNeeded();" />
<input id="slide3" type="text" value=""
onchange="ShowPointsNeeded();" />
</div>
<div id="result" style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid #999; font-size:25px; text-align:center; margin-left:15px;"></div>
```

Comment: If we change the inputs for the second time, result will be wrong.

Comment: @NisheshPratap thanks for pointing, missed that, code corrected.

Answer (score 1):

If want to calculate sum, of all inputs then you can use below logic :

```js
function ShowPointsNeeded(){
           //while doing calculation you have to consider all textboxes every time, 
           //so you have to derive a way to get all your related textboxes at once, 
           //e.g. : i have use name attribute to make all input boxes relate to each 
           //other.
            var allInputs = document.getElementsByName("numbers");
            var sum=0.0;
            for(var i=0;i<allInputs.length;i++){
                if(allInputs[i].value.length>0)
                sum= sum+parseFloat(allInputs[i].value); 
                //parsing float because user can input decimals as well
            }
            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=sum; 
        }
```

```html
       <div id="text">
        <input id="slide" type="text" value="" name="numbers"
        onchange="ShowPointsNeeded();" />
        <input id="slide" type="text" value="" name="numbers"
        onchange="ShowPointsNeeded();" />
        <input id="slide" type="text" value="" name="numbers"
        onchange="ShowPointsNeeded();" />
        </div>
        <div id="result" style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid #999; font-size:25px; text-align:center; margin-left:15px;"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this code, it seems like it works. Now, is there a way to do it without changing the name or the id of the input ? Sorry for asking !

Comment: You have to tell JS which input fields you want to consider in calculation. If you want to calculate sum of all inputs on the page then you can use **querySelectorAll** and then you can get all inputs as  `var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='text']");`

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript `Number()` function for convert from text to number:

```js
function ShowPointsNeeded() {
  var values = [];
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    values.push(elements[i].value);
  }

  var sum = values.reduce(sumElements, 0);

  var resultElement = document.getElementById("result"); 
  resultElement.innerHTML = sum; 
}

function sumElements(total, num) {
  return Number(total) + Number(num);
}
```

```html
<div id="text">
  <input type="text" value="" onchange="ShowPointsNeeded(this);" />
  <input type="text" value="" onchange="ShowPointsNeeded(this);" />
  <input type="text" value="" onchange="ShowPointsNeeded(this);" />
</div>
<div id="result" style="height:50px;width:50px;border:1px solid #999; font-size:25px; text-align:center; margin-left:15px;"></div>
```

For inputs don't needs `id` attribute.